# Como eu poderia fornecer um conjunto de valores de uma função no Javascript para um while do Python?

Tags: javascript, python

A ideia é que, enquanto estiver rodando um loop while no código Python, este irá receber um vetor de valores de uma função qualquer no Javascript e trabalhará em cima desses valores. Exemplo:

No arquivo Python (neste caso, o vetor userCommand sempre será renovado a cada laço):

```
while True:
    userCommand = ....vetor recebido do JS no formato [command, arg1, arg2, arg3]....
    if(userCommand[0] == 1):
        functionA(userCommand[1], userCommand[2])
        userCommand[0] = 0
    elif(userCommand[0] == 2):
        functionB(userCommand[1], userCommand[3])
        userCommand[0] = 0
    elif(userCommand[0] == 3):
        functionC(userCommand[3])
        userCommand[0] = 0

    etc...
```

E no arquivo Javascript, algo assim:

```
function(number1, number2)
{
    command = [3, number1, number2]
    ...enviar para o arquivo Python de modo que userCommand = command....
}
```

Comment: Passa o vetor como [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-pt.html).

Comment: Se pudesse explicar um pouco mais sobre o que está tentando fazer, talvez possamos sugerir uma maneira melhor de fazer esta implementação. Para mim o que descreveu aí é uma arquitetura cliente-servidor. E esses `ifs` que possui em seu código python seriam as rotas...com http method (get post) para cada operação.

Comment: Por exemplo quando o usuário clicar um botão na página da web. O javascript então vai acionar aquela função com alguns parâmetros, por exemplo as coordenadas da tela do clique, vai armazenar os valores num vetor e mandá-lo para o arquivo python que já estará sendo executado, preso num while, num loop infinito. A variavel userCommand no arquivo Python sempre vai ficar esperando receber algo do JS

Comment: O problema então não é o que passar, mas como passar os dados. Isso implica em saber para onde passar os dados. Esse programa python está sendo executado no cliente ou está sendo executado no servidor?